# How to upgrade office JavaScript ExcelApi

Tags: office-js

[image]
I use

I want to use ExcelApi 1.2~ 1.5.

But When I check my ExcelApi version, This is 1.1.

How to upgrade my ExcelApi version?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on O365 plan, you can get the [latest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/install-latest-office-version) Office version to use the new APIs. If you have the MSI version (Office-2016, but service patch updates only), then you'll have to upgrade to O365 (It appears that you have the MSI version looking at your version#. I can't be 100% sure). Excel online offers the latest version always.